# Javascript editor warning "Too many errors" w/ maxerr:1 and no identified errors

Tags: javascript, editor, warnings, strict

I'm editing a Javascript .js file with a few global variables and a collection of function definitions. I'm getting a little yellow triangle with an exclamation in the left margin. Hovering over it displays the message "Too many errors."

At first, this appeared around the middle of the file. I moved stuff around until I had eliminated all identified errors, i.e., little red square with x in it and description on hover. But the warning triangle persisted.

I set the first line of the file to "// jshint maxerr:1" after reading copious amounts on this topic including but not limited to the jshint options documentation. I tried various options and the only option that had any effect was adding ", strict:false" to the first line. That made the warning go away. Otherwise, with maxerr:1, the warning appears on line 2, which is "var x = 0;".

If I delete the global variables or move a function definition to begin on line 2, the warning appears on the line of the first statement in the function: e.g., alert('hello, world'); or if (true) { or var x = 0;. It doesn't appear on the function abc() { line and it doesn't appear on subsequent blank lines. If I leave the function empty, the warning doesn't appear on the terminating } line either. IOW an empty function is okay, whether or not it has a parameter in the parentheses. It just seems to have problems with statements.

It did (and does) tell me about errors in the file. And I was able to fix the errors it found, which it did a perfectly good job of identifying. Now, it doesn't indicate any error, it just says there are too many.

Which leads me to believe (a la Spoon Boy) *"Do not try to fix the error. That's impossible. Instead, only try to realize the truth ... There is no error."*

Editor with warning sans strict:false (or strict:true which appears to be the default
[image: Editor with warning sans strict:false (or strict:true which appears to be the default]

Editor without warning strict:false
[image: Editor without warning strict:false]

Comment: What editor is this?

Comment: The editor is cPanel Ace editor.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was likely a bug in Ace Editor, it is not reproducible right now.

Answer (score 2):

Adding zeros to the end of the 1 will increase the amount of lines that are searched before that warning is returned. For instance, use '// jshint maxerror:1000' to stop evaluating after the one thousandth line of code, and so on.

Comment: The answer is right, but the correct JSHint option is `maxerr` and not maxerror. 
According to the doc [link](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#maxerr).